# Who is the third Detective with Scully and Hitchcock?

Tags: brooklyn-nine-nine

In episode 1 (pilot) of Brooklyn Nine Nine, Terry is running through each of the detectives with Holt. He starts with Scully and Hitchcock, and one other detective.

After that, she is never seen again. What was her name (character and actress) and what happened to her? Why was she removed from the show?

Comment: She doesn't even show up in the cast and crew for ep. 1 on IMDB

Comment: She wasn't in main cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to IMDB Trivia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2936284/trivia?item=tr4062038) that's detective Daniels:

> When Terry is pointing out people in the squad to Captain Holt, you see Scully and Hitchcock with a female middle-aged detective, Daniels, and they are introduced as a group. After this point Daniels is never seen again, and Scully and Hitchcock are instead seen as partners.

Comment: Why was the character removed, and what was the actress' name?

Comment: @Ben I couldn't find such info. see also https://www.reddit.com/r/brooklynninenine/comments/2u4yfo/so_what_happened_to_det_daniels_woman_in_the/